# Multiple instance access of an application in weblogic server 12.2.1

Tags: java, weblogic, oracle-adf

Technical Issue: We have one ADF application deployed in different managed server under same domain with different context root path. But if user access this application from both URL (from different managed server deployments), one of the session get expired message.

Some clarification we have related to it:

1. Is it possible to achieve multiple instance of an application
   accessed by same user in different browser windows in same PC
   without clashing the sessions?
2. Will this solve by having multiple  or partitions or security realms
3. Weblogic Domain Partitions\ it available for ADF Applications

Application and Server Version Info

1. Application Server - WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.0.0
2. Application Framework – ADF,  JDev 12.2.1
3. Database – ORACLE 12C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have overcome this issue my setting different listening IP address to each managed server, these IP address has to be configured as server network's alternate IP also